# Firefox: what is the parameter to know if the cache will be cleared when closing the browser?

Tags: firefox, privacy, browser-cache, privacy-protection

in the list of paramters after outputting about:config, what is the parameter to know if the cache will be cleared when closing the browser?

Answer (score 1):

The preference name is

```
privacy.clearOnShutdown.cache
```